# How to unlock the next cell by clicking the previous cell of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Question: how to block the input to `cell` (№ 2,3,4,5 ...)? and how to make it so that when you click on №1 `cell` opens №2 `cell`? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array with the indexes of unlocked rows.

```
var unlockedRows: [Int] = [1]
```

Now you can check if the row is unlocked or not in `didSelectRowAt` delegate.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if unlockedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
        let nextIndex = indexPath.row + 1
        if nextIndex < numberOfRows { //Use your variable that gives total number of rows here instead of numberOfRows
            unlockedRows.append(indexPath.row + 1)
            // Do other stuff like removing the locked icon of the next cell
        }
        return true
    }
    // Display row locked message?
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need one flat to define who is unlocked.
Then when you click you add 1 to this flag to unlock the next cell.

```
private var unlocked: Int = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if(unlocked == indexPath.row) {
       self.unlocked += 1;
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell

    cell.myCellLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    if(indexPath.row > self.unlocked) {
     // put the locker
    }
    return cell
}
```